# Always receive 'You Lose' message in RPS against computer

Tags: python

For my exercise, I have to get the computer to play against the user in RPS. However, after both the computer and I input our action, the user will always receive a 'You Lose'.

```
    import random

def get_computer_move():
    """Deterministic 'random' move chooser"""
    options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    return options[random.randint(0, 2)]

def game_result(move1, move2):
    """game_result *exactly* as defined in question one"""
    options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    if move1 == move2:
        return 0
    elif move1 == "paper" and move2 == "rock":
        return 1
    elif move1 == "rock" and move2 == "scissors":
        return 1
    elif move1 == "scissors" and move2 == "paper":
        return 1
    else:
        return 2


def main():
    """Runs a single game of PSR""" 
    print("Let's Play Paper, Scissors, Rock!")
    user1 = input("Player one move: ").lower()
    computer1 = print("The computer plays " + get_computer_move())
    game_result(computer1, user1)
    if user1 == computer1:
        return print("It's a draw")
    elif user1 == "paper" and computer1 == "rock":
        return print("You win")
    elif user1 == "rock" and computer1 == "scissors":
        return print("You win")
    elif user1 == "scissors" and computer1 == "paper":
        return print("You win") 
    else:
        return print("You lose")    
    
main()
```

Here is my code although it is quite messy.

What I want to happen is:

```
Let's Play Paper, Scissors, Rock!
Player one move: ROCK
The computer plays rock
It's a draw
```

But it will always come out as:

```
Let's Play Paper, Scissors, Rock!
Player one move: ROCK
The computer plays rock
You lose
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo He does `input("Player one move: ").lower()`, isn't that correct?

Comment: additionally, why do you do comparisons and return numbers from `game_result()` if you are going to do all the comparisons again in `main()`?

Comment: either save and use the return value from `game_result()` or delete the function and just do the comparisons in `main()`. also, you don't need the `options` list in `game_result()`, even if you do end up keeping the function.

Comment: @Esther - The docstring from `game_result` would make it seem as though thats a separate part of the homework, not related to this question directly

Comment: @Sayse I assume they are supposed to use the result in `main()' though, not just call it and forget about it.

Comment: @Esther - Possibly, but thats a different issue to the one the op is asking about

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

print returns none, you want to save the computers move and then print that separately

```
computer1 =  get_computer_move()
print("The computer plays", computer1)
```

Comment: Hi there, with this method it still doesn't resolve my issue, although the flow of things does feel cleaner.

Comment: @PrancisJeremy - What does that mean? what happens now?

Comment: I still receive 'you lose' no matter what the user nor the computer inputs. I should be receiving a 'You won!' or 'It's a draw'.

Comment: @PrancisJeremy - https://ideone.com/kRf26A, that shouldn't be possible with the code shown

Comment: I've just tried out the code you linked me and it worked, thanks a bunch! Would've gone insane otherwise.